# Show the status of daily file loads from mysql database

Tags: mysql, sql

I am working on a project where we receive some files daily which are loaded into the database, their status is recorded into meta-data.

For e.g.,
There are 2 different clients from which we get three different type of files, type_a, type_b and type_c.

```
CLIENT_MASTER
----------------------
client_id|client_name
1|xxx
2|yyy
```

File status is stored in FILE_MASTER table

```
FILE_MASTER
-----------------------------------
file_key|client_id|filename|status
1|1|type_a_2010-10-07.csv|12
2|1|type_b_2010-10-07.csv|12
3|1|type_c_2010-10-07.csv|12
4|2|type_a_2010-10-07.csv|12
5|2|type_b_2010-10-07.csv|12
```

The status keys are stored in STATUS_MASTER table

```
STATUS_MASTER
-------------------
status_key|status
12|Completed
```

I want to develop a dashboard showing status of daily file loads, in the below format -

```
Client|type_a|type_b|type_c
xxx|Yes|Yes|Yes
yyy|Yes|Yes|No
```

Any help on this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query will return result for current date:

```
SELECT cm.client_name,
       CASE WHEN v.type_a_count > 0 THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END AS type_a,
       CASE WHEN v.type_b_count > 0 THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END AS type_b,
       CASE WHEN v.type_c_count > 0 THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END AS type_c
FROM client_master cm
     LEFT OUTER JOIN (
        SELECT fm.client_id,
               SUBSTRING(fm.client_name, 8, 10) AS file_date,
               SUM(CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(fm.client_name, 1, 6) = 'type_a' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS type_a_count,
               SUM(CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(fm.client_name, 1, 6) = 'type_b' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS type_b_count,
               SUM(CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(fm.client_name, 1, 6) = 'type_c' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS type_c_count 
        FROM file_master fm
        WHERE SUBSTRING(fm.client_name, 8, 10) = CURDATE()
          AND fm.status = 12
        GROUP BY fm.client_id, SUBSTRING(fm.client_name, 8, 10)
     ) v ON cm.client_id = v.client_id
```

Comment: Thanks @Kirill, this works almost as expected, but one case where it is not ideal is when there are no files for a client, it will not show a record for that client. For e.g., for a client, xxx, there were no files today, it only shows only one row -  yyy|Yes|Yes|No, but it should show 2 rows, as xxx|No|No|No and yyy|Yes|Yes|No

Comment: Could you please help me with this?

Comment: I've updated my solution for this case. Please try it.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
SELECT c.name,
IF(FIND_IN_SET('type_a', GROUP_CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(f1.filename,'_',2))), 'Yes', 'No') as type_a,
IF(FIND_IN_SET('type_b', GROUP_CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(f1.filename,'_',2))), 'Yes', 'No') as type_b,
IF(FIND_IN_SET('type_c', GROUP_CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(f1.filename,'_',2))), 'Yes', 'No') as type_c
FROM client_master c
JOIN file_master f1 ON(f1.client_id = c.client_id)
JOIN status_master sm ON(sm.status = f1.status)
WHERE sm.status='Completed' AND SUBSTRING_INDEX(f1.filename,'_',-1) = CURDATE()
GROUP BY c.id
```